# Overwrite parts of audio stream using FFmpeg (or DaVinci Resolve)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, davinci-resolve

##### FFmpeg

I have a video of a funeral ceremony, speech interspersed with three pieces of music of a couple minutes each. Audio quality is sufficient for speech, but it would be nice to have the music played back in the chapel be overridden by the audio files it originated from (and which already has a "chapel sound" of its own, being a live recording of a choir). Inputs would be:

- `vid.mp4` - video + audio (AVC/AAC), 40 minutes
- `{1,2,3}.m4a` - audio files (AAC) of about 4 min each

This would seem to involve inserting the music files at their respective timestamps (at 10, 20, 30 min) and then fading them in while muting or fading to zero the original audio for the duration of the playback.

Some `-filter_complex` is required, but using which particular filters precisely? Using `amix` and specifying 0 in `weights`? Or rather `afade` or `acrossfade`? Or something else? Involving `anull` or `apad`? And `asetpts` might also be necessary.

While going through the list of `ffmpeg -filters` doing `A->A`, I noticed there is also `astreamselect`. This might be the easiest provided I pad the three music files with silence to line up with the audio track from the video.

Another solution might involve the `volume` filter. So what's the best practice on this one?

---

##### DaVinci Resolve

[image: Tracks in DaVinci Resolve on the Edit Page]

What I've managed to accomplish is aligning the video+audio to the millisecond with an additional audio recording of the speech (second green track) and the three pieces of music (third green track).

What's left to do is to overwrite the parts of the additional speech track with the music tracks at precisely the positions they've been aligned to.

So the task seems simple and I should be able to do it using the *Overwrite Clip-F10* function, which appears on the Edit Page, but not on the Cut Page. The Overwrite action is desribed in the 4000 page reference manual in the Cut Page chapter » Fast Editing in the Cut Page » Drag and Drop Editing. Haven't read the entire manual yet and can't figure out how to perform the overwrite as the action cannot be performed on the Edit Page for some unknown reason (icon stays greyed out) and the icon is missing on the Cut Page (where I can drag and drop, losing alignment precision, and where for some reason the additional speech track only appears in the upper pane, not in the lower pane). Advice welcome. :)

Okay, so in order to perform the overwrite on the Edit Page, the item must be selected in the left-hand pane so it appears in the Source Viewer, and then the track where it is to be inserted must be selected in the Timeline in the bottom pane, and of course the playhead snapped into the proper position. And then a click on the icon performs the overwrite.

Comment: `So what's the best practice on this one?` Not using ffmpeg. GUIs exist for a reason.

Comment: I often wonder why people struggle with command-line video solutions when one of the world's finest video editing suites is available ***free*** for personal use. [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix.

Comment: Yes, for convenience and time efficiency, this is best done in a visual editor. But no need to install a NLE. In fact, I don't think they will allow you to save the output without recompressing the video. Use ffmpeg to extract all audio to WAVs then load and align the tracks in Audacity or in an NLE if you want. Encode and mux the output with the original video.

Comment: Thanks all. I was not familiar with video editing GUIs and never heard about DaVinci Resolve or NLE (non-linear editing). It sounds like Audacity would be sufficient in this case, but as the video originates from a cellphone, it needs to be compressed anyway, so I might actually try the DaVinci option. Will report back once I get this done. Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: "DaVinci Resolve could not initialize OpenGL. Please ensure that the latest graphics drivers are installed." - They are, version 10.18.10.5161 from Aug 2020 for Intel HD 4000 (Core i3-3225 Ivy Bridge CPU with 16 GB RAM). But DaVinci won't start. Windows 10 22H2. - Download of DaVinci 18.6 is 2 GB. I cancelled the installation of some drivers which I assumed were for the separate special keyboards that DaVinci sells. Don't think that had anything to do with the failing or missing OpenGL.

Comment: I've never run it on Windows , but it will run fine on Mac, which only uses legacy OpenGL 2.1. Last driver for your chipset was 15.33.53.5161 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/81499/graphics/processor-graphics/intel-hd-graphics-family/intel-hd-graphics-4000.html

Comment: Chipset driver package `win64_15.33.53.5161.exe` contains display driver `10.18.10.5161` from 6 Aug 2020. My system, including the Intel driver, is up to date. Memory assigned to GPU per BIOS is 1024 MB (maximum). I don't have a Mac, only an outdated Hackintosh on this Ivy Bridge system. Apparently DaVinci works best with an NVIDIA card. Will try using a GTX 660 I have lying around.

Comment: Wish you luck. Strictly, the HD4000 chipset is barely supported in Win10. they made one interim driver back in 2015, then the one we're talking about, which I call the 'late apology' driver in 2020. [I wish they'd get their numbers sorted out - if you can't install it you can't see what the internal driver version is, only the package exterior. I don't have anything in the building with that chipset - I just know it as it was 'famous' during the transition to Win10 for not being properly supported. I worked helpdesk for an online game at the time; it was a nightmare.]

Comment: Thanks for your info. Yes, driver support seemed a bit disappointing over the years, I even went back to Windows 7. The number that matters most in the driver version might be the last segment, `5161`. - So, success with the NVIDIA card. DaVinci starts up and allows me to do stuff, AFAICS. Now have to figure out how to make use of this NLE. Will post the solution once I get it done, just for completeness.

Comment: Excellent news. let us know how it goes :)

Comment: Now you've got what is essentially a different question using DaVinci, I'd be tempted to ask this on https://video.stackexchange.com/ - I'd do it with volume curves, but I'm not a video suite expert, I'm a sound engineer.